# MySQL: Syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ':'

Tags: mysql, temp-tables, dynamicquery

I want to create temp table dynamically. I am passing column name as a parameter to stored procedure.

**Example**:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure sptemp(IN nm varchar(50))
BEGIN

SET @q = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable    // Error occuring here @q 
             SELECT DISTINCT ', nm ,' AS Col FROM table1');
PREPARE d FROM @q;
EXECUTE d;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE d;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Error**:  Syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ':'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @q = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temptable (INDEX(Col)) ENGINE=MyISAM 
AS (SELECT DISTINCT ', nm ,' AS Col FROM table1)');
```

As a bonus - index of your Col column.